# Changing the value of a NSIndexPath object

Tags: iphone, cocoa

If I have an index path with value : { 0, 0}.  What is the proper way to change it to { 0, 1} ?  I know if it were an ordinary c array it would just be :

```
unsigned i_array[] = { 0, 0};
i_array[1] = 1;
```

But from NSIndexPath's documentation, the closest I can get is with :

```
– indexPathByRemovingLastIndex
– indexPathByAddingIndex:
```

It seems a bit cumbersome.  Is there a way that I can just overwrite the last member of the index array ?

Comment: Try something like `indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section + 1];`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NSIndexPath` is not an array. It's an object with 2 readonly properties: `row` and `section`. You can't change them, however, you can create a **new** indexPath based on the old one:

```
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:oldIndexPath.row inSection:1];
oldIndexPath = newIndexPath;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Your answer uses a convenient method to create the newIndexPath so it does not need to be manually released.  So if an init method were used, a release statement has to be added, is it right ?

Comment: Yes, if you don't use ARC. This method returns autoreleased object.

Answer (score 0):

```
indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, and do not provide a code snippet only.